# Check if textbox has empty value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var inp = $("#txt");

if(inp.val() != "")
// do something
```

Is there any other way to check for empty textbox using the variable 'inp'

Comment: should you check by using trim too ?

Comment: Why is `inp.val() != ''` not adeguated?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

```
if (inp.val().length > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

if you want anything more complicated, consider regex or use the [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) which takes care of this for you

Comment: you don't need > 0 in this case as far as i can tell. if the length is 0, it will be like if(0), and the condition will fail.

Comment: or simply if (inp.val())

Answer (score 99):

```
var inp = $("#txt").val();
if(jQuery.trim(inp).length > 0)
{
   //do something
}
```

Removes white space before checking. If the user entered only spaces then this will still work.

Comment: It is the perfect solution!

Comment: @Grimmy I like the fact that you included `trim`. That makes this answer  complete.

Comment: Why not be consistent? Either use `$` or `jQuery` but why both?

Answer (score 17):

```
if ( $("#txt").val().length > 0 )
{
  // do something
}
```

Your method fails when there is more than 1 space character inside the textbox.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following to check if text box is empty or have more than 1 white spaces

```
var name = jQuery.trim($("#ContactUsName").val());

if ((name.length == 0))
{
    Your code 
}
else
{
    Your code
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason to have two pairs of braces on that `if`?

Answer (score 7):

```
$('input:text').filter(function() { return this.value.length > 0; });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( $("#txt").val().length == 0 )
{
  // do something
}
```

I had to add in the == to get it to work for me, otherwise it ignored the condition even with empty text input. May help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Also You can use

```
$value = $("#txt").val();

if($value == "")
{
    //Your Code Here
}
else
{
   //Your code
}
```

Try it. It work.

Answer (score 4):

The check can be done like this:

```
if (!!inp.val()) {

}
```

and even shorter:

```
if (inp.val()) {

}
```