# How to check for an empty input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if textbox has empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565193/check-if-textbox-has-empty-value)

How do I check if an input value is blank?

I am currently doing:

```
if($(#inputid).val()=="") {
    alert("its blank");
}
```

Comment: Don't you have an error here? It should be $('#inputid').val())

Comment: Keep the JavaScript error console open while you're testing. The error messages are shown there.

Answer (score 4):

Try quoting your selector string:

```
if ($("#inputid").val() == "") {
    ...
```

You might want to trim to stop whitespace from counting:

```
if ($.trim($("#inputid").val()) == "") {
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if( !$.trim($("#inputid").val()).length ) {
  alert("blank");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what you have wanted to write :).

Comment: Yes. You are right. Is it OK now? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
if (!$('#id').val()) { 
    //is blank 
}
```

Comment: Actually, you've got your logic wrong. That if-clause will only execute if the value is NOT blank.