# JQuery how can i check if the textbox is empty

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to know if the textbox is empty when i change of textbox, how can i do it? i tried to create a script, but i totally failed.

I'm new at jQuery.

Here my js script

```
$("#description").blur(function())){
if ($("#description").val() == "") alert ("Empty!");
}}
```

I want to know if my textarea is empty or not

```
<label>Description</label>
<textarea cols="55" rows="3" id="description" name="description">
</textarea>
<br><br>
```

What do i need to do? I dont want to call a function inside the textarea

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if textbox has empty value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565193/check-if-textbox-has-empty-value)

Comment: do spaces count as empty???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#description").blur(function(){
if ($("#description").val() == ""){ alert ("Empty!")};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in dom ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#description").blur(function () {
        if ($("#description").val() == "") alert("Empty!");
    });
});
```

aLso your syntax has some mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Use change

```
$("#description").on('change',function(){
  if(this.value == "") alert("Empty");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
       //do something
     }
});
```